# How do I get this to render in IE6?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

Cannot work out how to get the following menu to display correctly in IE6, any ideas?

Demo: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/vimeo_navigation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few key things to remember that are relevant to this menu:

- Forget transparent PNGs in IE6 (possible to get them working but not a great experience)
- Forget `display:inline-block` in IE6
- Forget `z-index` in IE6
- Forget `:first-child` and `:last-child` in IE6

Basically, what you have to do is:

- Use transparent GIFs or non-transaparent PNGs
- Instead of `display:inline-block`, use `float:left` and friends
- You don't really need `z-index` for this menu anyway
- You will have to decorate first and last children with classes manually

**EDIT**: IE6 doesn't support CSS selectors like "`#menu > li`", you will have to use "`#menu li`".

Comment: have removed all inline-block and z-index and used float: left now.

still the menu does not align horizontaly.  I am not bothered about the PNGs, just want the menu to run along the top not stacked in IE6

Comment: Oh yes and IE6 doesn't support immediate descendant selectors like "#menu > li", see my edit. Changing it to "#menu li" will fix the layout (more or less, you will still have trouble with margins but that's easy to solve)